# I can't run C# console application ( version `GLIBC_2.32' not found)

Tags: c#, rider, ubuntu-21.04, jetbrains-rider

I am on Ubuntu 21.04 and running a C# console application in *Jetbrains Rider*.
And it says:

```
/home/Door/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/ConsoleApp1: /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
```

What is the problem? And how can I solve this?

Comment: JetBrains knows the issue and the solution already, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-73736

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few weeks ago and i think this helped me:

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/error+%2Flib%2Fx86_64-linux-gnu%2Flibc.so.6%3A+version+%60glibc_2.32%27+not+found

Maybe try to update your ubuntu version first, current is 22.04

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution for that specific Rider issue, and there is no need to upgrade Ubuntu.

Comment: OK i have another question: where did you get your dotnet sdk? From snap? Coz i remeber that i had issues with this source.

Comment: That link didn't helped. I don't still understand why but the problem was inside the dotnet sdk installed with `snap`.
I freshly installed everything with `apt` following the microsoft documentation and it's working now.

Comment: Yeah i had same problem with snap .net sdk.